# how to add module with __main__.py to executable path bash/zsh

Tags: python, bash, zsh

I have a package that uses **main** in a module to run the package as an executable.  I am having trouble figuring out how to add this module to the system path so I can `package` from anywhere. The structure looks like this:

```
Package
── pacakge
   ── __main__.py
```

Adding /path/to/Package to PATH env variable does not work allow me to call `package` in bash or zsh. What am I missing?

`__main__.py` has executable permissions and calling `python /path/to/Package/packge` works fine.

Comment: Write a wrapper script with content `python /path/to/Package/packge` and add that wrapper to the system path.

Comment: Thats basically want I am doing,  I wanted the command to look like `package ...` not `package.sh .....`. I am using `alias package='python /path/to/package'`

Comment: AFAIK you are not obligated to give a `.sh` extension to your scripts. You can go with file name `package` as long as you have a proper shebang at the start of your script.

Comment: You are correct, I can put it in a bin dir and add that to PATH.  I was just hoping for a way around this doing that with the structure I already have. Thanks